# Custom taxonomy [year] is directing to yearly archive

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

My custom taxonomy is linking to yearly archive instead of the post linked to it.

I have created a custom taxonomy named "year" containing int (i.e 2008,2009,2010 etc). Have registered the custom taxonomy using the following code.

```
// Add new "Years" taxonomy to Posts
register_taxonomy('year', 'post', array(
// Hierarchical taxonomy (like categories)
'hierarchical' => true,
// This array of options controls the labels displayed in the WordPress Admin UI
'labels' => array(
        'name' => _x( 'Year', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Year', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Years' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Years' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Year' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Year:' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Year' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Year' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Year' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Year Name' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Years' ),
    ),
    // Control the slugs used for this taxonomy
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'Years', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
        'with_front' => false, // Don't display the category base before "/Years/"
        'hierarchical' => true // This will allow URL's like "/Years/boston/cambridge/"
    ),
));
```

and echoed the year taxonomy under post using the following line.

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'year', '<li>', '</li><li>', '</li>' ); ?>
```

I have registered two other taxonomies "player" and "team" in the same manner which are working perfectly.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise against the use of `year` as a post type or taxonomy name as its a reserved term and your rewrite rule may clash

[For a list of reserved terms see here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms)

Steps to take:

- Modify the URL rewrite so it doesn't clash
- Change the name of the taxonomy from `year` to something unique that isn't reserved

Comment: Thanks Tom for your instant reply. Let me change it, i'll let you know the result!

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom. Changing the name to "year_" fixed the issue. Check it out                                   http://cricketclips.net/669/paul-collingwood-to-sumit-narwal/